# Facebook iOs SDK 3.1, What if i dont upgrade?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

What would be the immediate consequences of not upgrading to the Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 ?

How long more I can keep using the old 2.x API  ?

Comment: Depends on your definition of the current SDK. (the current SDK is 3.1.1 since oktober 2012)